# Disable/change colors in vim terminal (but not in open file)

Tags: vimrc, neovim, terminal, colorscheme

I'm on Mac Neovim. When I type `:term`, I am greeted by this:
[image]

This poses some issues; For example when I run a command, it also colors the output; I don't want this to happen. Is there some way to change the terminal colors or completely disable it?

**Note 1:** Setting `termguicolors` didn't fix this

**Note 2:** The normal terminal (non vim one) color is different, and ok.

EDIT: Looks like this issue extends beyond the terminal:
[image]
As you can see here, stuff like `nerdtree` and all are getting underlined and colored. This is *not* due to the colorscheme; The same happens with the default colorscheme. How do I fix all this?

Comment: are you talking about your prompt colors? Or where exactly? If for the prompt, than configure your prompt to not emit colors when run from neovim terminal

Comment: Could be related to `:help g:terminal_ansi_colors` or the particular terminal emulator and `$TERM`. You can sometimes request no colors by setting the environment variable `NO_COLOR`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt -- The colors when I'm editing a file in neovim are fine. The colors when I'm working in the terminal *outside* of nvim are fine. The terminal *inside* of vim (when I type `:term`) is the problem and the screenshot above.

Comment: I'm not sure, but this might have something to do with my colorscheme (palenight)...

Comment: I just tested out another color scheme, and the issue was still there, albeit with different colors.

Comment: @obr So is it about the prompt colors or not? Then configure your shell to not output any colors in the prompt

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt -- If I set `$TERM` to `NO_COLOR`, then don't get any colors in nvim. I want no (or the default) colors in the terminal opened inside of nvim; I still want color in the terminal opened outside nvim. I've also updated the post... The issue appertnly extends beyond the terminal.

Comment: @obr I still don't understand. please clearly describe where you want colors and where not. And where you see color differences. Perhaps a screenshot showing those color differences might be helpful. Note: you may want to consider to set the environment vairable  `NO_COLOR` only inside the terminal of vim

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it! It was the spell check in the terminal causing the issue! I added this to my config:

```
autocmd TermOpen * setlocal nospell
```

Now it doesn't highlight in the terminal.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble -- Yep, probably. Fixed it.